# Need help finding out what type of url encoding is this?

Tags: url-redirection

I need to know what type of encoding is involved in this url string:

http://www.newcarfax.com/chevy-vehicles/?bmv3y2fyzmf4lmnvbq=Nw==86aPMTU4YTo1OntzOjQ6InBhZ2UiO3M6MzM6Imh0dHAlM0ElMkYlMkZ3d3cubmV3Y2FyZmF4LmNvbSUyRiI7czo3OiJrZXl3b3JkIjtzOjE2OiJ0cnVjaytkZWFsZXJzK2luIjtzOjM6InNyYyI7czo2OiJ0cnVja3MiO3lSd1oeSM6NDoia3dyZCI7czoxNjoidHJ1Y2srZGVhbGVycytpbiI7czo1OiJzdWJpZCI7czoxNDoidHJ1Y2tzKy0rY2hldnkiO30=&kwrd={ifContent:{placement}}{ifSearch:{keyword}}

This was used for SEO purposes and I would like to do the same if possible. An application was used to create this and I'm not a programmer to figure out how it was created besides what what data I typed in it to create it.

PLease, help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a base64 : http://www.base64decode.org/

Even though am answering this question, am pretty sure this will be closed as it is not a constructive question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I couldn't get it to decode using a bas64 decoder... :/ Atually nvm it worked!!!! ThX!!! :)